# Generate random unique code - php

Tags: php

How do I generate a random code/PIN. I read PHP's **rand()** and **mt_rand()** functions and it seems to do good but I found there are duplicates.

Can someone suggest or demonstrate a better way of achieving this in PHP?

my code:

```
$size = 1000; //handcoded pin-size

function generatePIN($size =500){
$pins = array(); $i = 0; //ini counter
//my basic algorithm for generating unique pin codes
    while ($i < $size){
        $pin = (mt_rand(100000,999999));
        $pins[] = $pin;
        ++$i;
    }
sort($pins);//sort in lowest to highest
return array_unique($pins);//remove duplicates
}

//call it and print or store in database
 $pins = generatePIN($size);
 foreach ($pins as $pin) {
    echo $pin.'<br>';
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check in your loop if the value already exists in your array?

Comment: read about `uniqid` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding to the generated value in the loop solved the problem is its very efficient calling it each day. No matter how long the size is.

```
$size = 1000; //handcoded value

function generatePIN($size =500){
    $pins = array(); $i = 0;
    //my basic algorithm for generating unique pin codes
        while ($i < $size){
            $pin = (mt_rand(100000,999999)) + (mt_rand(1000,9999)) + strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$i.' week')));
            $pins[] = $pin;
            ++$i;
        }
    sort($pins);//sort in lowest to highest
    return array_unique($pins);//remove duplicates
    }

//store in database or print it
    $pins = generatePIN($size);
    foreach ($pins as $pin) {
    echo $pin.'<br>';
    }

    echo "<hr />";
    echo count($pins);
```

Answer (score 0):

A true random always has the chance to create a duplicate, because it is unconditional to the previous given randoms.

To make a duplicate less likely you can increase the random interval with `mt_rand(10000000,99999999)`.

Or you can check if your number was a duplicate:

```
while ($i < $size){
    $pin = (mt_rand(100000,999999));
    if (array_search($pin, $pins) === FALSE) {
        $pins[] = $pin;
        ++$i;
    }
}
```

This will perform more poorly the bigger `$size` is compared to the random interval and create an endless loop if `$size` is bigger than it.

Comment: you code is only not appending to the $pins array. This will shorten the $size of the pins I want to generate. I think array_unique() will do this job without using if conditions. Thank you anyway

Comment: Using `array_unique` will remove all duplicates and therefore return an array that is smaller than `$size`. My code only increases `$i` if a pin is added and therefore creates an array of the size `$size`. Yet, if returning less fields than `$size` is acceptable for your logic, yours is the better way to go.